# Mark sides of a sector without shifting document

Tags: tikz-pgf, exam, tkz-euclide

I am trying to mark the two radii of this sector as equal using \tkzmarksegment, however, when doing so, the image disappears. This is for the purposes of a maths homework booklet. I have included the question for the first column as well so that testers can see how the sector ends up being affected. Can anyone show me how to do this easily? One of my ideas was to calculate the coordinates of the third corner of the sector but I know that can't be done with relative ease so was wondering if there was something simpler?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calculator}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagestyle{head}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\bracketedpoints
\pointsinrightmargin

\question[10] Find the perimeter of the following (2 marks each)
        \setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{parts}
            \part
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]

                    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
                    \coordinate (b) at (2,4);
                    \coordinate (c) at (4,0);
                    \coordinate (d) at (2,1);
                    \draw (a) -- (b) node[midway,left=4.5pt]{1.02 m} -- (c) -- (d) node[midway,below=.3cm]{420 cm} -- cycle;
                    
                    \tkzMarkSegment[pos=0.5,mark=||](a,b);
                    \tkzMarkSegment[pos=0.5,mark=||](b,c);
                    \tkzMarkSegment[pos=0.5,mark=|](c,d)
                    \tkzMarkSegment[pos=0.5,mark=|](d,a)
                \end{tikzpicture} 

            \part
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]

                    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
                    \coordinate (b) at (12,0);
                    
                    \draw (a) -- (b) node[midway,below]{12 cm} arc[start angle=0, end angle=60, radius=12 cm] coordinate (c)-- (a) node[midway,left=+2pt]{12 cm};
                    
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{parts}
        \end{multicols}   
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your code is not minimal. You can remove all unnecessary packages. Use a simpler class.

Secondly, it's bad practice to mix `TikZ` and `tkz-euclide` even if it's possible. It's like loading hundreds of macros just to mark segments. If you need to make a lot of geometrical figures, `tkz-euclide` is a suitable tool, but if you're comfortable with `TikZ` then work only with it.

Finally, `tkz-euclide` or pgfplots loads `TikZ`, so you don't have to load it yourself.

```
\documentclass[margin=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/a,2/4/b,4/0/c,2/1/d}
\tkzDrawPolygon(a,b,c,d)
                   
\tkzMarkSegments[pos=0.5,mark=||](a,b b,c)
\tkzMarkSegments[pos=0.5,mark=|](c,d d,a)
\tkzLabelSegment[above left= .5 em](a,b){1.02 m}
\tkzLabelSegment[below=.5 em](c,d){420 cm}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/a,12/0/b}
\tkzDefPoint(60:12){c}

\tkzDrawPolySeg(c,a,b)
\tkzDrawArc(a,b)(c)
\tkzMarkSegments[pos=0.5,mark=||](a,b a,c) 
\tkzLabelSegment[below = .5 em](a,b){12 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[above left=.5 em](a,c){12 cm}                
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you need to put a label on the arc, you have `\tkzLabelArc`

[image]